# How to create a Core Data Relationship in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, set, nsset

I have two entities in my data model:  Student <-->> Grade

In Objective-C I can use the following line to link the relationship of my two objects:

```
[newStudent setValue:[NSSet setWithObject:newGrade] forKey:@"grades"];
```

However in Swift, there is no NSSet. How do I perform the same thing?

```
newStudent.setValue(??????, forKey: "grades")
```

Comment: I misspoke when I said "there is no NSSet". I meant that there was no native set in Swift. However, as gregheo pointed out, I see now that Swift 1.2 added a new 'Set' type. I'd like a solution using this native Set.

Comment: Have you used the native Swift 'Set' type as an '@NSManaged' property successfully? I'm not able to find anyone confirming that is works properly online.

Comment: I ended up using subclasses like Martin R suggested. When Xcode auto-generated the subclasses, it defined the attributes like:

`@NSManaged var gradesRelationship: NSSet`

Then in my code I used Swift Sets something like this:

`var thisGradeSet:Set<NSObject>?
var thisGrade:GradeElement?

thisGradeSet = thisStudent!.gradesRelationship.filteredSetUsingPredicate(cellPredicate)

var thisScore:Int = thisGrade!.score as Int

thisScore = 95

thisGrade!.score = thisScore`

Comment: Whoops! Sorry about the formatting in my comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already said, you can use `NSSet` to assign the to-many relationship.

But it is actually easier to assign the inverse (to-one) relationship 
from `Grade` to `Student`:

```
newGrade.setValue(newStudent, forKey: "student")
```

This will automatically update the inverse relationship, i.e. *add* the `newGrade` object to the `grades` property of `newStudent`.

And what you actually should do is to create `NSMangedObject` subclasses
for your entities (in the "Xcode-> Edit" menu) and then use the
property accessors:

```
newGrade.student = newStudent
```

This is easier to read, easier to write, you do not run the risk of 
typing errors in the key strings, and the compiler can perform
a proper type checking.

Answer (score 7):

There sure is `NSSet` in Swift:

```
newStudent.setValue(NSSet(object: newGrade), forKey: "grades")
```

In Xcode 6.3 and Swift 1.2, there's a native `Set` type too. This usually bridges over `NSSet` to `Set<NSObject>`.

Comment: Could you please show me how it's done using `Set` in Swift 1.2? Thank you!